# Android failed to merge Manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest, androidx

I know this type of question has been asked before, but my problem was not solved with those answers.
Today I added a new version of PayU Money into my app and suddenly it shows an error. I have converted the whole project into **androidx**, the same error comes.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:31:5-163:19 to override.

If I added this **tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory** inside Manifest file it show new error

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

On checking Manifest Merger it shows

> Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:31 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 30 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)

I can not figure out the error. Here is build.gradle(app)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.packagename"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 54
    versionName "5.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
 repositories {
google()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
maven {
    url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
  }
 }

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'

implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.0'
implementation 'com.wefika:flowlayout:0.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation project(':sdkui')
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.zopim.android:sdk:1.4.2'

/* Snappydb (cache/db) */

/*For shimmer effect*/
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.snappydb:snappydb-lib:0.5.2'

   }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: are you using andoridx??

Comment: @BhoomikaPatel Right now i removed androidx and get back to normal code

Comment: check my below answer. Normally i used this solution whenever i got this kind of error. and this solution works for me evry time. Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this 2 lines inside your `<application />` tag of your manifest

```
   tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
   android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

this helps me. Hope this can also helps you.

You should **try this once**. You also need to add this line.

```
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

For GoogleAPIClient intialization you should use this in your AppCompactActivity:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
```

remove `enableAutoManage()`
`enableAutoManage()` requires a `FragmentActivity` or some subclass of that, such as `AppCompatActivity`. You cannot use `enableAutoManage()` with a regular Activity. Either:

- Switch your code to use `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`, or
- Do not call `enableAutoManage()`

Comment: I did, now it shows another error - error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FragmentActivity

Comment: From where your MainActivity extends??

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener and it imports from import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Comment: your error is because of GoogleAPIClient. check my updated answer

Comment: check now @SanwalSingh

Comment: From where I should remove enableAutoManage

Comment: The whole working fine till afternoon, then after I added PayU Money's new sdk and error comes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200010/discussion-between-sanwal-singh-and-bhoomika-patel).