# Android Manifest doesn't exists or has incorrect root tag Error in Android Studio BumbleBee 2021.1.1 RC 1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am using **Android Studio BumbleBee 2021.1.1 RC 1**

I Got this Error while I am running my project

*(other project not showing any error like this.)*

**SCREEN SHOT :**
[Error : Android Manifest doesn't exists or has incorrect root tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k46KI.png)

I had tried all the solutions , comment given in this link but not fixed :

*(tried almost all solution in stack over flow)*

1. [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424135/android-studio-android-manifest-doesnt-exists-or-has-incorrect-root-tag)
2. [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452319/error-androidmanifest-xml-doesnt-exist-or-has-incorrect-root-tag)
3. [Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58115300/9987478)

**--------------Solution That I tried---------------------**

1. Sync project with Gradle files
2. Invalidate Caches and Restart....
3. Delete .gradle/.idea/ folder
4. Clean Project & Re-Build
5. Re-Created a new project and move all files to their. (tried as in case if manifest file corrupted)
6. Downgraded target sdk version to 30.
7. Upgrading/Downgrading Gradle version.
8. In AS **terminal** run
   *`./gradlew clean assembleDebug`*  (but still not fixed.)

I am attaching **stacktrace** by running *`./gradlew build --stacktrace`* (which gives error details)

> > Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for
> > details.
>
> > Task :app:minifyReleaseWithR8 AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing classes detected while running R8.
> > Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are
> > generated in D:\Android Project\DigiSchool BackUp\PlayStore\12 Aug
> > 2021\EvvStudy\digi-schoo\app\build\outputs\mapping\release\missing_rules.txt.\n","sources":[{}]}
> > AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class
> > kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope (referenced from:
> > kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
> > id.zelory.compressor.Compressor$compress$3.p$ and 1 other
> > context)","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
>
> > Task :app:lintDebug Wrote HTML report to file:///D:/Android%20Project/DigiSchool%20BackUp/PlayStore/12%20Aug%202021/EvvStudy/digi-schoo/app/build/reports/lint-results-debug.html
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 8.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
> individual deprecation warnings. See
> https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

**Still facing that issue please help me in to this.**

Comment: Go Terminal, `cd ` to locate your project, and execute `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` or some other variants' building tasks. If it goes well, then fire a ticket to AS team via Google's issue tracker, it's just an IDE bug, we can do nothing but using CLI instead. If it shows some more errors, paste errors stacktrace here. So people can know and help.

Comment: @2BAB thanks for your time, I had tried your solution still not solved. So I **updated** my Question with StackTrace

Comment: Sorry but I did not see any error that is related to AndroidManifest.xml. The R8 warnings you may want to check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70226816/cannot-access-kotlinx-coroutines-coroutinescope-which-is-a-supertype-of-andro
However above log is the gradle task execution log, how was the final build result, if the error happened it should show an exception like runtime exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer right now since I was facing the same issue without founding any solution.

On Android Studio go to:

```
File -> Project Structure (Ctrl+Alt+Maiusc+S) -> Facets -> Structure -> Manifest file:
```

Change the path of the file, the path is under

```
YOURAPPNAME\android\app\src\main
```